# My keybindings.json has no effect on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the default behaviour from "ctrl + d" to "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction".
I added the required setting in keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+d",
    "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
}
```

But still the default behaviour for "ctrl + d" is executed ("Add selection to next find match")
My keybindingService-Log is looking good:

```
Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyD, keyCode: 68, key: d    
Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: KeyD, keyCode: 34 ('D')    
Resolving ctrl+D    
From 1 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.copyLinesDownAction, when: no when condition, source: user.    
Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.
Clearing single modifier due to 300ms elapsed.
```

What am i missing?

edit: provide full log

edit: I did some more testing and my keybindings.json seems to have no effect at all. I'm jusing Jupyter Notebooks for VSCode. Maybe there is something to override it?

Comment: I see that any find match on a line to be duplicated "goes with" the duplicated line - and leaves the original line.  Is that what you are referring to and trying to avoid?  If so, try binding `editor.action.copyLinesUpAction`  to `Ctrl+D` instead.

Comment: Not really, i can't duplicate any line with ctrl+d.
Instead the default keybinding for ctrl+d is executed (even though I deleted it and set a new keybinding for ctrl+d.
I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: It works for me and I don't have to disable `"-editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch"` either. So very strange.

Comment: I did some more testing and my keybindings.json seems to have no effect at all. I'm using Jupyter Notebooks for VSCode. Maybe there is something to override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like VSCode does only host a Jupyter instance and can not change the keybindings inside. So there is no way to edit keybindings for Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode